# EcomDev PHPUnit - test that URL is secure

Tags: ecomdev-phpunit

I have configured my custom router/controller/frontname to be forced to use SSL using the "secure_url" node in my config.xml. Does anyone know how I can write a test using EcomDev PHPUnit to confirm this is working?

In addition is there a way to test for duplicate xml nodes in my config files?

This all came about because I inadvertently duplicated a node name which caused my route not to be forced to use SSL. Below is an example:

```
<secure_url><module_one>frontname</module_one></secure_url>
<secure_url><module_one>frontname_two</module_one></secure_url>
```

The second node overrides the first since module_one is duplicated as the node name. The result is that frontname is not forced to use SSL.The above xml was in two different modules.

Answer (score 3):

In your test case you can test the value of the `Request` object.

```
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->isSecure();
```